# mysql_skip_secure_auth not skipping secure auth

Tags: perl, perl-module, dbi

**Edit**: From what I can tell, the root cause of this problem is that the right Perl modules are being installed, but the wrong `mysql.so` file is being loaded.

```
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:"
    . "database=$db;"
    . "host=$dbhost;"
    . "mysql_ssl=$dbssl;"
    . "mysql_skip_secure_auth=1;";
```

I recently attempted to upgrade our version of DBD::mysql, but kept coming across the `DBI connect('database=mydb;host=myhost','myuser',...) failed: Connection using old (pre-4.1.1)` error.

After many hours of debugging, and determining that the *correct* option of not updating the password hashing methods of our mysql tables was not possible with our overall system, I found that with [DBD::Mysql 4.027](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.027/lib/DBD/mysql.pm) you could declare "mysql_skip_secure_auth" as part of your dsn.

However, this doesn't seem to work.

If I run`mysql -h $myhost -u $myuser -p --skip-secure-auth`, I am able to connect without incident, but trying to do this with DBI/DBD::mysql, I always run into the error above, as if the directive is being ignored.

- [Relevant documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.027/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#Class_Methods)

I have also tried using `mysql_read_default_file` with the same option set, as well as simply `mysql_skip_secure_auth` in the DSN. No combination of any of these things has worked.

Am I missing something?

EDIT:

Trace output (edited to remove sensitive information):

```
imp_dbh->mysql_dr_connect: host = |{host}|, port = 0, uid = {user}, pwd = {pwd}
imp_dbh->mysql_dr_connect: Skipping secure auth
imp_dbh->bind_type_guessing: 0
imp_dbh->use_server_side_prepare: 0
imp_dbh->mysql_dr_connect: client_flags = 2
imp_dbh->mysql_dr_connect: <-           --> do_error
Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled) error 2049 recorded: Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)




my $versions = DBI->installed_versions;
foreach (keys %$versions) {
    print "\n$_: " . %$versions->{$_};
}

DBD::SQLite: 1.26                                                               
DBD::ExampleP: 12.014310                                                          
DBD::Sponge: 12.010002                                                             
DBD::Gofer: 0.015057                                                             
DBD::DBM: 0.06                                                                    
DBD::mysql: 4.027                                                                  
DBI: 1.618
```

Comment: Understand that pre-4.1 passwords are [officially deprecated](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-upgrades.html) and support for them will be removed in a future release. At some point, you will have to upgrade to the new password hashing. For your immediate problem, turn on DBI's [tracing](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#TRACING) before your `connect` statement to see what's going on behind the scenes: `DBI->trace('3|CON');` I see this in the trace output: `imp_dbh->mysql_dr_connect: Skipping secure auth`

Comment: Thanks for the trace idea. Unfortunately, the password problem isn't mine to solve. I've alerted the team responsible, but that's about all I can do.

Comment: Edited with info from the trace.

Comment: `perl -MDBD::mysql -e 'print $DBD::mysql::VERSION'` will show the version of DBD::mysql being used by your Perl. I'm guessing you're not actually using 4.027 since I get `imp_dbh->mysql_dr_connect: Skipping secure auth` immediately after `imp_dbh->mysql_dr_connect: host = ...` in the trace when I run with 4.027; with 4.013, no such message.

Comment: `bin/env -e {EnvironmentName} /env/{EnvironmentName}/bin/perl -MDBD::mysql -e 'print $DBD::mysql::VERSION'`
4.027%

Comment: Perhaps add the `print $DBD::mysql::VERSION` to the top of the script you're having issues with, just to make sure. I highly doubt this would affect it, but maybe double check that DBI is also up-to-date.

Comment: DBI is 1.631, which as far as I know is the latest. I'm about to just compile with a hard-coded 1 for this value in the driver itself. If that doesn't work, it would mean that I'm somehow linking to the wrong mysql.so.

Comment: the print statement in the script is giving me an empty string (sorry if you got notifications of other comments; I didn't realize it was an empty string so i was drawing false conclusions). However, This script in particular isn't requiring or using the DBD module, just DBI.

Comment: I added a 'use' statement in order to get the version, and it also confirmed that it's using 4.027.

Comment: You're right, sorry. Instead of the print call `DBI->installed_versions;` after `use DBI;` to show the version of all installed drivers. I would take out the `use DBD::mysql;`

Comment: Did that; copied output above. I'm stumped.

Comment: Ohhh. Wait a minute! That version of DBI is 1.613, not 1.631. I will find where that dependency lies and update the shit out of that. But I'm about to head out for the day, so may not be able to respond for a while.

Comment: I'm stumped as well. Not sure if updating DBI would fix it but it's worth a shot. Just for reference, what are your Perl and MySQL versions?

Comment: Mysql client is 5.6; server instance is (I believe) 5.5. Perl is 5.8. Whcih I know is bad, but it's another legacy issue.

Comment: Updated the trace output. I now see the "skipping secure auth", but then two lines later, it still gives the same error. Moving in the right direction, at any rate.

Comment: Was this after upgrading to the latest version of DBI?

Comment: After, among other things, like triple checking and cleaning up dependencies, and so forth to limit variables that could cause the problem. Doing a debug mode running the script, everything looks fine until we pass everything into the mysql.so file. I think it's loading the wrong one, as there are still others scattered about the system.

Comment: Well, I wish I could say that I knew what the problem was, but after more cleanup, more recompiling and installing, and more frustration, it's working now. I'm going to have to close this issue. But know that you have been golden in helping me debug. I don't know if it will help if I upvote your comments to give you rep if the issue is closed, but I'm going to try anyway.

Comment: Glad you got it working! (even if you're not sure what the exact fix was; but hey, that happens sometimes) You might post an answer saying what you *think* solved it, just in case someone has a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that things are a little tricky in this area, but the challenges seem to stem from the C mysql lib rather than DBD::mysql.

First, pass the param as a driver option rather than as part of the main DSN string:

    `my @dsn = ("DBI:mysql:database=$db;host=$dbhost;mysql_ssl=$dbssl",
    $user,
    $pissword,
    { mysql_skip_secure_auth => 1 });`

That should work as long as you are not using a .cnf file.

To authenticate via a file there are some constraints.

    `my @dsn = ("DBI:mysql:"database=$db;host=$dbhost;mysql_ssl=$dbssl;"
    . "mysql_read_default_file=$absolute_path.cnf",
    undef,
    undef,
    { mysql_skip_secure_auth => 1 });`

Ensure your file does not contain an entry for `secure_auth`, otherwise the C lib mistakenly treats it as enabled, even if the entry has it disabled.

Any line similar to this, with a disabling (falsy) value

    `secure_auth = FALSE`

must be changed to

    `skip_secure_auth`

(and confirm that standard tools such as mysql and mysqldump work as before).

The C lib has a bug in that it treats `secure_auth = FALSE` as `secure_auth = TRUE` and in my opinion it has a second bug in that it ignores `skip_secure_auth` instead of honouring it.

According to the documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-options.html secure_auth options are not generally supported, but it is strange that one form is (mis)implemented while another form is ignored.

The above 'works' if your code knows it is connecting to a v4.0 server, but I would much rather not mess the code with server-specific logic.  I'm still hoping there's a way to get the C library patched so this can be done purely via the .cnf file as the standard tools do.

As an addendum, if there's some reason you cannot use `skip_secure_auth`, you will need to omit all secure_auth entries from your `[client]` section and instead add `secure_auth = FALSE` to each section needed by your tools, ie `[mysql]`, `[mysqldump]`, etc, which is clearly horrible.

Comment: where can the C API be found on Mac, I have been searching it for quite some time but can seem to find it...

Comment: So is it not possible to disable secure auth on a client library that defaults it to be on?

Answer (score 0):

For my Mysql 5.0, this turned out to be an issue with the old_passwords.  I changed the secure_auth = ON to troublshoot, and had the following error:

> failed: Server is running in --secure-auth mode, but 'user'@'hostname' has a password in the old format; please change the password to the new format

The mysql server had stored the passwords in the 16 char hash.  After updating to the 41 char hash, I was able to connect.  No mysql_skip_secure_auth entries were needed.  Also returned the server to secure_auth = OFF

I was also able to keep the server as old_passwords=1

Instructions for upgrading the passwords
http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/upgrading-passwords-from-old_passwords-to-new-passwords